# React not showing the same value of mapped item in the same mapping sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, material-ui

Ive got  some standard mapping going on.

```
{MEMBERSHIPS.map((mItem, index) => (
                <TableCell
                  className="text-uppercase text-center"
                  colSpan={2}
                  padding="dense"
                  value={mItem.label}
                  key={mItem.key}
                >
                  <Button onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>{mItem.label}</Button>
                  <Dialog
                    disableBackdropClick
                    disableEscapeKeyDown
                    open={this.state.open}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                  >
                    <DialogTitle>
                      Choose bulk edit {mItem.label} status
                    </DialogTitle>
```

**`...`**

The value of `{mItem.label}` is correctly pulling through the headers, but if I use that key again within the mapping staetment it brings back the last item in the array... I would expect `{mItem.label}` to be the same wherever its used.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kxrk5mnqjr

If you go to the above codesandbox... click on a heading of either seniors, Juniors or Infants - this is a button

```
<Button onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>{mItem.label}</Button>
```

It opens up a dialog where I want to use the heading value again `{mItem.label}` but the result is different from the header display. e.g. If I clicked the Seniors button I would expect the Seniors dialog text however it comes back with "infants" in all instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using the same state value to open/close all the dialogs `this.state.open`. So when you click on one button, all 3 dialogs are opened, and you see the last one which is on top.

To fix this :

```
  handleClickOpen = value => {
    this.setState({ [`open${value}`]: true });
  };

  handleClose = value => {
    this.setState({ [`open${value}`]: false });
  };
```

And

```
          <Button
            onClick={this.handleClickOpen.bind(this, mItem.value)}
          >
            {mItem.label}
          </Button>


         <Dialog
            disableBackdropClick
            disableEscapeKeyDown
            open={this.state[`open${mItem.value}`]}
            onClose={this.handleClose.bind(this, mItem.value)}
          >

          ...
```

Complete code https://codesandbox.io/s/pm0ovrvl97